# ng test -code-coverage is throwing Disconnected Reconnect failed before timeout of 2000ms after migrating to ANGULAR 14

Tags: karma-jasmine

**This is happening only after upgrading to angular 14. This I have tried.**

**All the tests are running successfully but at the end I am getting the below error.**

Chrome Headless 117.0.5938.132 (Windows 10) ERROR
Disconnected reconnect failed before timeout of 2000ms (server shutting down)
Chrome Headless 117.0.5938.132 (Windows 10): Executed 90 of 90 SUCCESS (1.522 secs / 1.235 secs)
Chrome Headless 117.0.5938.132 (Windows 10) ERROR
Chrome Headless 117.0.5938.132 (Windows 10): Executed 90 of 90 SUCCESS (1.522 secs / 1.235 secs)
C:\Users\git\apps\testApplication\node_modules\karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter\index.js:121
var suite = suites[browser.id]
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'manual-123' of null
at SonarQubeUnitReporter.onBrowserComplete (C:\Users\git\apps\testApplication\node_modules\karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter\index.js:121:23)
at Server. (C:\Users\git\apps\testApplication\node_modules\karma\lib\events.js:40:26)
at Server.emit (events.js:387:35)
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\git\apps\testApplication\node_modules\karma\lib\browser.js:117:22)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)

**Versions I have :**
node:14.17.3
npm: 6.14.13
"karma": "~6.3.17",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
"karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
"karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter": "~0.0.23",

**I already have the the following on karma.config file**
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
Flags: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox']

**Tried upgrading the karma packages to the latest version. But no luck.**
**Also Tried adding the followng in karma.config file. but no luck**
`captureTimeout: 210000,browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,browserDisconnectTimeout : 210000,browserNoActivityTimeout : 210000,`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue. Most of the articles pointed to configs below.

1. Time-out configs in karma.config captureTimeout: 60000,browserDisconnectTimeout : 10000, browserDisconnectTolerance : 1, browserNoActivityTimeout : 60000,
2. flags in karma config flags: [ --disable-gpu, --no-sandbox ] But in my case
   I had all these configs.still got "disconnected reconnect failed before timeout error" on Jenkins and on my local after running all the tests successfully. The Root cause for this issue was a test case in my code that was using deeplink which caused tests to stuck & timeout.